# Pi-hole and OpenVPN on Raspberry 3 B+ ¿Ubuntu server or raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu

I have not decided on any. Which do you think is better for this combination, and why?

OpenVpn handles only one connection and pi-hole at most three.

Comment: Welcome @rai. Please explain what you want? OpenVPN and Pi-hole are not the same kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to ask which OS to use then the answer is always Raspbian Buster.

Take a look at PiVPN which should work with PiHole under Raspbian.